# Automate acceptance of license terms in order to download file

Tags: python, web, spynner

I need to download a file, but in order to do so, I have to accept license agreement.

For example, from

`http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html`,

I would like to download

```
 Linux x86  146.84 MB     jdk-8u40-linux-i586.rpm
```

I thought about something like:

```
browser = spynner.Browser()
url = "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html"
browser.load(url)
browser.runjs("acceptAgreement(window.self, 'sjre-8u40-oth-JPR');")
file = browser.download("http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u40-b26/jdk-8u40-linux-i586.rpm")
if file == None or file == "":
    print("Wrong")
else:
    data = file.read()
    with open("code3.rpm", "wb") as code:
        code.write(data)
```

but it always says "Wrong" so there is probably nothing in the `file` variable.

Can someone please give me a hint?

Comment: You might have a typo, you wrote hhttp instead of http.

Comment: Sorry, just missspell :) in my program its ok.

Comment: You have to accept the licence when downloading from oracle

Comment: I know, thats why I have "browser.runjs("acceptAgreement(window.self, 'sjre-8u40-oth-JPR');")" in my script. But propably its not working so my whole question is how to accept them and download a file.

Comment: Yes but I mean you have to sign in

Comment: When I am signed in a browser, that doesn't count?